# problem while copying information from one spreadsheet to another on google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to extract and organize some information from one spreadsheet to another one with a script.
So far I have been able to do very little stuff since I'm totally new to scripting.
There is some stuff that seems beyond my understanding.

I want to copy from "1_Test-CONCEPTION 2D/3D" to "02"

here is my code so far:

```
function fill_planning_data_sheet() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let COsheet = ss.getSheetByName('1_Test-CONCEPTION 2D/3D');
  let PLsheet = ss.getSheetByName('02');
  
  //créer entête colonnes
  PLsheet.getRange('G1:L1').setValues([['2D PROJECT','2D TASK', '2D NAME', '2D START D', "2D DD", '2D PROGRESS']]);

  //remplir le projet
  COsheet.getRange(2, 1, COsheet.getMaxRows(), 1).copyTo(PLsheet.getRange(2, 7));

  //remplir les Task
  COsheet.getRange(2, 9, COsheet.getMaxRows(), 1).copyTo(PLsheet.getRange(2, 8));

  //remplir les Name
  COsheet.getRange(2, 10, COsheet.getMaxRows(), 1).copyTo(PLsheet.getRange(2, 9));

  //remplir la date de début
  PLsheet.getRange(2, 10, PLsheet.getMaxRows(), 1).setValue('01/01/2023');
  //PLsheet.getRange(2, 11).setValue('01/01/2023');
  //sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).setValue('01/01/2023');

  //remplir la Date BAT
  COsheet.getRange(2, 11, COsheet.getMaxRows(), 1).copyTo(PLsheet.getRange(2, 11));

  //remplir les progress
  COsheet.getRange(2, 12, COsheet.getMaxRows(), 1).copyTo(PLsheet.getRange(2, 12));

}
```

and here is what it produces:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVLGg.jpg)

I have three problems:

1. In the project column, the code copies a "formula" instead of copying the value (I bet the function I use is not the good one...).

what I want to copy is in green, and what it copies is in red.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQGW8.jpg)
so here is the "result"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egBeh.jpg)

I have to say that, in a perfect world, I would have this information (in green) repeated as many times as there "task"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKubP.jpg)

2. In my original spreadsheet there isn't a `start date`, so I want to create it myself, I tried to copy the end date on the start date column and then to replace all the values by using: `.setValue('01/01/2023')`
   but I failed. So I tried to fill it with `PLsheet.getMaxRows(), 1).setValue('01/01/2023')`, but of course, it goes on and on and creates 940 copies of the date, which is not perfect at all.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb0FJ.jpg)
3. I also would like the project line to be filled with the project name as much as there is task.
   what I get now:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJYzF.jpg)

what I want:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K65T.jpg)

Any help?
thanks!

Comment: Don't post an additional question as an answer.  Simply edit your original post (OP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to copy the values of COsheet column A to PLsheet column G and fill in the blank cells with the previous cell value.

Replace

```
COsheet.getRange(2, 1, COsheet.getMaxRows(), 1).copyTo(PLsheet.getRange(2, 7));
```

With

```
//remplir le projet
let values = COsheet.getRange(2,1,COsheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
// skip the first row of values assuming it alread has a value
for( let i=1; i<values.length; i++ ) {
  if( values[i][0] === "" ) values[i][0] = values[i-1][0];
}
PLsheet.getRange(2, 7, values.length, 1 ).setValues(values);;
```

And to fill in the PLsheet column J with the date use `getLastRow()` instead of `getMaxRows()`.  Notice I used it above as well.  Note also I subtract 1 from `getLastRow()` because you want from row 2.

Replace

```
PLsheet.getRange(2, 10, PLsheet.getMaxRows(), 1).setValue('01/01/2023');
```

With

```
PLsheet.getRange(2, 10, PLsheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).setValue('01/01/2023');
```

Reference

- [Range.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,CopyPasteType,Boolean))
- [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())

Answer (score 0):

If you need the calculated value (i.e. in cell A1 with formula `=10/5` and value 2) and you need to copy the value `2` rather than the underlying formula, you have two choices:

1. Keep using `copyTo` but specify the `copyPasteType`: `copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)` -> `copyTo(destination, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)`. You can read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type for the available copy-paste mode
2. Use `copyValuesToRange()`

For the second problem, rather than using `getMaxRows()`, try to use `getLastRow()` on a Range class where you need to have the date placed. This way you can be sure that the date were only written to the row that needs that information.

```
let range = "K1:K";
let selection = PLsheet.getRange(range);
let last_filled_row = selection.getLastRow(); // integer

range = range + last_filled_row.toString(); // concat "K1:K" with the column ending row

PLsheet.getRange(range).setValue('01/01/2023');
```

That's just an example, you can make the whole thing one-liner.